# last item get deleted when clicked on the first item in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView.inflated from an ArrayList of objects. I have added a delete button on the item and I want to delete the clicked item. But when clicked instead of the clicked item the last item gets deleted.no matter what item clicked always the last item is deleted. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Adapter:

```
    public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<NotificationItem> mNotificationList;
    private onItemClickListner mListner;

    private Context myContext;
    private int layoutResID;

   public interface onItemClickListner{
     void onItemClick(int position);
     void onDeleteClick(int position);
    }

//    public void setOnItemClickListner(onItemClickListner listner){
//       mListner=listner;
//    }

    //NOTIFICATION HOLDER
    public static class NotificationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView mNotificationTextView;
        public RelativeLayout mNotificaionHolderLayout;
        public ImageView imageDelete;
        onItemClickListner listner;


        public NotificationViewHolder(View itemView,final onItemClickListner listner) {
            super(itemView);
            mNotificationTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.NotificationTextView);
            mNotificaionHolderLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification__item_container);
            imageDelete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_delete_image);
            this.listner=listner;


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   if (listner!=null){
                       int position=getAdapterPosition();
                       if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                           listner.onItemClick(position);
                       }
                   }
                }
            });

            imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listner!=null){
                        int position=getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listner.onDeleteClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }//NOTIFICATION HOLDER

    public NotificationAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NotificationItem> notificationList,onItemClickListner listner){
        myContext=context;
        this.layoutResID=resource;
        mNotificationList=notificationList;
        this.mListner=listner;
    }


    @Override
    public NotificationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_notificationitem,parent,false);
        NotificationViewHolder evh=new NotificationViewHolder(v,mListner);
        return evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotificationViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NotificationItem currentItem=mNotificationList.get(position);
        holder.mNotificaionHolderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Getcolor(position)));
        holder.mNotificationTextView.setText(currentItem.getNotifi_Name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNotificationList.size();
    }

    private String Getcolor(int position)
    {
        String clr;

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                clr="#FF9966";
                break;

            case 1:
                clr="#009900";
                break;

            case 2:
                clr="#006699";
                break;

            case 3:
                clr="#751947";
                break;
            case 4:
                clr="#FF9966";
                break;

            case 5:
                clr="#009900";
                break;

            case 6:
                clr="#006699";
                break;

            case 7:
                clr="#751947";
                break;


            default:
                clr="#FFA500";
                break;
        }
        return clr;
    }

}
```

Home activity:

> I have implemented the NotificationAdapter in home class and override the functions.and set the adapter to the recycler view.

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    FlashMessage("SOMETHING");
    nfAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    nfAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    nfAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position,listNotifi.size());
}

@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
       FlashMessage("DELETED ON POSITION : " +position);
       listNotifi.remove(position);
       nfAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       nfAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
       nfAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position,listNotifi.size());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the RecyclerView Adapter is set up to reuse views off screen, declaring the listener within the ViewHolder declaration is bad practice.

If your onClickListeners rely on the position of the item within the whole list, you will want to know that position, not the position within the adapter list itself. (That is the point of the adapter, is that it reuses it's views for memory. It's best to just keep the holder class to declare public variables to xml view ids.) Simply move the lines:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if (listner!=null){
                   int position=getAdapterPosition();
                   if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                       listner.onItemClick(position);
                   }
               }
            }
        });

        imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listner!=null){
                    int position=getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listner.onDeleteClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

to your onBindViewHolder, like so:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NotificationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NotificationItem currentItem=mNotificationList.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                   //listener stuff using position from onBindViewHolder input
        }
    });

    holder.imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                //listener stuff using position from onBindViewHolder input
        }
    });

    holder.mNotificaionHolderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Getcolor(position)));
    holder.mNotificationTextView.setText(currentItem.getNotifi_Name());


}
```

Comment: Yes. It worked. Using listener in Home activity or Holder is not going to work well.

Comment: This is the easiest way, I think. Maybe it's slightly more concise to declare the listener in the adapter and the callback method in the activity, but this is less prone to errors. I think the only problem is with memory for larger RV lists because all the listeners remain? I'm honestly not sure about that right now without rereading a bunch of dev references.